# HREF links not clickable

Tags: php, html, css

I've taken over the hosting of a website for a neighbour, the previous guy was messing them about and the website is an absolute mess!
My html skills are okay, but not too in depth.

Anyway, for some reason the links on the footer of the website aren't clickable. I've Googled the hell out of it and I still can't figure it out. The CSS sheet is a minefield.

Any help would be greatly appreciated https://mobilecaravanvaleting.co.uk/

Thanks.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 Sorry but how do you expect me to add meaningful code when I've stated I don't know what part of the website is causing it!?

Comment: I expect you to work on your issue and pare the code down to a minimal example that demonstrates the issue, as the [mcve] link above explains. Otherwise once your issue is fixed, this question will be of no use to future visitors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `footer` block is overlapped with some `div`.

[Image](http://prntscr.com/ve7v3y)

Comment: I did try but the site won't allow me yet...
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 1):

remove this div `cp-info-bar-wrapper cp-clear` and it should work

Comment: Thank you, that's sorted it!

Comment: @user3212595 I know you cant upvote yet, which is fine, but you should be able to accept an answer. This helps future users know which solution ended up doing the trick and helps other answerers know that a solution was found. Thanks!